# Failed to initialize Vuforia Engine

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

Im trying to embed my vuforia project to my flutter app,

Everything runs fine at first open, but idk why everytime i open the app again, the error pop up on the unity screen:

The problem i could specify is, Vuforia try check / get / something about the Camera Permission, since the first open it ask for Camera Permission, it run good, but second, while the permission already granted, the error show up.
I tried to ungrant the permission, open app again, it work again because it request for the permission.

Any suggestions of what and where the thing must i change? It's quite annoying to ungrant the permission everytime i open the app.

Regards, Slim!

[Vuforia error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlRdS.jpg)[image]

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me when I have Vuforia running in the Editor (playing a game) and changing some code while it's running. Then, when coming back into Unity, it stops playing because of recompiling. But that apparently causes Vuforia to crash, and it will come up with that error screen on the next play.

My workaround is to stop a running game in Unity before changing (saving) any code, so recompiling doesn't crash Vuforia.

Comment: Re-reading your question, my problem may be a lot different than yours, though. So my solution may not be relevant at all in your case.

Comment: I think it's similar, only differ that i already deployed the release app to my phone, while you still on the unity editor. So the problem is on the recompiling? How can i implement that stop function on the app then?

Answer (score 0):

Close and re-open Unity. This cleared it instantly for me. NOTHING else was called for. You'll save yourself a LOT of heartache and a lot of unnecessary work.